# Unable to install specific version of apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, installation

I pretty new to this, My distro is Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed apache2 latest version, which is available in repositories,(i.e.,2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9).

I have used this command,`apt-get install lamp-server^` , where I'm a getting a dependency error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1) but 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9 is to be installed`

So I'm trying to Install apache2 of 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 version, but when I run this command:

```
apt-get install apache2=2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1
```

I get this Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Output of :`apt show apache2-mpm-prefork -a`

`Package: apache2-mpm-prefork
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 22.5 kB
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Apache Maintainers <debian-apache@lists.debian.org>
Source: apache2
Version: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1
Provides: httpd, httpd-cgi
Depends: apache2 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1)
Download-Size: 1,460 B
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: lamp-server, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, mythbuntu-backend-master
Description: transitional prefork MPM package for apache2
 This is a transitional package to apache2 for users of apache2-mpm-prefork and
 can be safely removed after the installation is complete.

Package: apache2-mpm-prefork
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 22.5 kB
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Apache Maintainers <debian-apache@lists.debian.org>
Source: apache2
Version: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
Provides: httpd, httpd-cgi
Depends: apache2 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4)
Download-Size: 1,462 B
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: lamp-server, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, mythbuntu-backend-master
Description: transitional prefork MPM package for apache2
 This is a transitional package to apache2 for users of apache2-mpm-prefork and
 can be safely removed after the installation is complete.`
```

So, I'm Unable to install that specific version of apache2.

Comment: Did you do `apt-get update`?  `apache2-mpm-prefork` should be on release v4.9 as well.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, I get same error, that it depends on = 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1

Comment: What does `apt show apache2-mpm-prefork` say?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't get where to post details, Here I have updated Question, Sorry for my improper Indentation

Answer (score 0):

There was some fault with dependency which seems to be unresolvable, There was a different approach which worked,

`sudo apt-get install tasksel` ,tasksel is a packages group utility, which will install several grouped packages during installation time so that there wouldn't be any errors, and it will automatically configure certain defaults, so that packages grouped would work well with integration.

To get all packages grouped tasks, execute this command,`tasksel --list-tasks`

It will list all available tasks, With this package it is easy to install certain standard grouped packages (named as tasks), such as kubuntu-active, kubuntu-desktop,xubuntu-live..... and many other.

So first install the base server with this command, `tasksel install server`,
then remove all lamp packages with this command `tasksel remove lamp-server`

, Now you have all necessary files for server installation, as packages are only temporarily removed use autoremove to completely remove lamp packages, with this command `sudo apt-get autoremove` ,

Then install lamp-server using tasksel, with this command: `tasksel install lamp-server`, that's it you are done with the installation.

***Warning: This package 'tasksel' is only available for Ubuntu as far as my knowledge***